# How to format this xml with Go to struct list?This xml tag name is the same, only the id is different

Tags: xml, go, xpath

I had a xml code, I want to format xml to struct list.
I try to use “encoding/xml”, but the api not support filter by ID inside the tag.
I want to format unionBankNo and bankName, but error.
Please tell me there is a better solution?

this is my xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<kColl id="noSessionSrvData" append="false"> 
  <field id="EMPException"/>  
  <field id="errorMessage"/>  
  <field id="customerId"/>  
  <field id="provinceCode"/>  
  <field id="provinceName"/>  
  <field id="cityCode" value="1000"/>  
  <field id="bankName"/>  
  <field id="bankType" value="104"/>  
  <field id="configName"/>  
  <field id="electricNo"/>  
  <field id="orderFlowNo"/>  
  <field id="dateTime"/>  
  <iColl id="iCityInfo" append="false"></iColl>  
  <iColl id="iBankInfo" append="false"> 
    <kColl id="null" append="false"> 
      <field id="unionBankNo" value="104100006610"/>  
      <field id="bankName" value="中国银行股份有限公司北京百子湾支行"/> 
    </kColl>  
    <kColl id="null" append="false"> 
      <field id="unionBankNo" value="104100004013"/>  
      <field id="bankName" value="中国银行股份有限公司北京市分行"/> 
    </kColl>  
    <kColl id="null" append="false"> 
      <field id="unionBankNo" value="104100004048"/>  
      <field id="bankName" value="中国银行股份有限公司北京崇文门支行"/> 
    </kColl>  
  </iColl>  
  <iColl id="iPayUseList" append="false"></iColl>  
  <iColl id="iBankNotice" append="false"></iColl>  
  <iColl id="iOrderList" append="false"></iColl>  
  <field id="activateCode"/>  
  <field id="payAccountOpenNode"/>  
  <iColl id="iCityBank" append="false"></iColl>  
  <field id="transferTowardType"/>  
  <field id="errorCode"/>  
  <field id="chargeFee"/>  
  <field id="userAlias"/>  
  <field id="password"/>  
  <field id="passwordEncrypted"/>  
  <field id="oldPassword"/>  
  <field id="passwordOld"/>  
  <field id="passwordNew"/>  
  <field id="userid"/>  
  <field id="flowId"/>  
  <field id="uifAlias"/>  
  <field id="stt"/>  
  <field id="queryNumber"/>  
  <field id="flagNo"/>  
  <field id="userId"/>  
  <field id="openDate"/>  
  <field id="turnPageBeginPos" value="1"/>  
  <field id="turnPageShowNum" value="10"/>  
  <field id="turnPageTotalNum"/>  
  <field id="queryType"/>  
  <field id="PBA_ID"/>  
  <field id="PBA_TYPE "/>  
  <field id="PBA_TITLE "/>  
  <field id="PBA_CONTENT "/>  
  <field id="PBA_TELLERNO "/>  
  <field id="PBA_DATETIME "/>  
  <field id="PBA_ACTIVEDATE "/>  
  <field id="PBA_EXPIREDATE "/>  
  <field id="PBA_STT "/>  
  <iColl id="iANNOUNCE" append="false"></iColl>  
  <iColl id="iUnionBankList" append="false"></iColl>  
  <field id="abateDate"/>  
  <field id="Dueday"/>  
  <field id="_ServletRequest" value=""/>  
  <field id="retValue" value="0"/> 
</kColl>
```

this is my struct

```golang
type UnionInfo struct {
    UnionNo string `xml:"field>[@id='unionBankNo']>id,attr"`
    BankName string `xml:"field>[@id='bankName']>id,attr"`
}

type Result struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"kColl"`
    Name    string
    City   string    `xml:"field>[@id='cityCode']>value,attr"`
    Province string
    UnionInfo []UnionInfo `xml:"iColl/kColl"`
}
```

```golang
err = xml.Unmarshal([]byte(body), &v)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("error: %v", err)
        return
    }

    fmt.Println(string(body))
    fmt.Println(v)
```

error: xml: field>[@id='cityCode']>value chain not valid with attr flagExiting.

Answer (score 0):

With `encoding/xml` you can first parse the xml into the *correct* structure and then after that filter the necessary stuff yourself. Whether there's a 3rd party package that makes this simpler I don't know...

```
type KColl struct {
    Id     string  `xml:"id,attr"`
    Append bool    `xml:"append,attr"`
    Fields []Field `xml:"field"`
    IColls []IColl `xml:"iColl"`
}

type IColl struct {
    Id     string  `xml:"id,attr"`
    Append bool    `xml:"append,attr"`
    KColls []KColl `xml:"kColl"`
}

type Field struct {
    Id    string `xml:"id,attr"`
    Value string `xml:"value,attr"`
}

func main() {
    var k KColl
    if err := xml.Unmarshal(data, &k); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    var res Result
    for _, f := range k.Fields {
        if f.Id != "cityCode" {
            continue
        }
        res.City = f.Value
        break
    }
    for _, i := range k.IColls {
        if i.Id != "iBankInfo" {
            continue
        }

        for _, j := range i.KColls {
            var info UnionInfo
            for _, f := range j.Fields {
                if f.Id == "unionBankNo" {
                    info.UnionNo = f.Value
                }
                if f.Id == "bankName" {
                    info.BankName = f.Value
                }
            }
            res.UnionInfo = append(res.UnionInfo, info)

        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", res)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/W4LnMLKVa8z

Comment: Thank you.Yours is the best solution at the moment.But is this possible with xpath api?

Comment: The `encoding/xml` package does *not* provide support for xpath. The [documentation on Unmarshal](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Unmarshal) enumerates the capabilities of the package when it comes to parsing xml. If xpath isn't listed there then there is no support for it. You'll have to look for 3rd party packages that provide that which you seek.

Comment: @Jetman I doubt it can get an easier. And it is a straightforward procedure: Build your structs, unmarshal (your XML is small enough), manipulate to your needs, marshal.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg Can you write me a simple demo for me? Or give a struct demo？